# Do we need nokia-beamer tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The Nokia beamer or photo beamer service has been discontinued by Microsoft. The app has been removed from the store. The tag [nokia-beamer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-beamer) contains a [Single post](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/4121/what-is-the-url-to-the-nokia-beamer-web-site) that is of poor quality. Do we need this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the tag has been removed. It is no longer shown.